# "0001-01-01" from string to date in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, null, as.date

I'm new in R. I had an issue with datetime function and hope that you guys can help.

I used as.Date() in R to convert a column of string into date. There are several cells with string "0001-01-01", which then stay the same after converting. What I expected was that those cells should be turned into null value. But it was not.   When I write the file in excel and open it, those cell ("0001-01-01") become -693593. I have no clue why.

I know I can just use gsub to replace those into null. But I hope someone can help me with a fancier functions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason is that all dates in excel originate from `1970-01-01`. Substract 693593 days from this and you probably hit `0001-01-01`. Convert these to null before moving to excel if that is what you expect, using something along the line of `df$date[df$date == '0001-01-01'] <- NULL`, changing both `df` and `date` to your data frame and the column respectively.

Comment: ".... in excel":  No, on real (Unix-alike) systems the epoch aka 1970-01-01 is the refernce point.  Excel actually has a different one.

Comment: Thanks Oliver and Dirk. I wonder if I can use one function to replace '0001-01-01' to NULL in all date columns?

Comment: Yes, that is relatively intuitive from the last code: `df[df == "0001-01-01"] <- NA`

Comment: Why don't you define it as an `na.string` when importing the data?

Comment: Note that `0`, `NULL`, `NaN` and `NA` are different concepts in R. A vector cannot contain `NULL`. Missing values are coded as `NA`.

Comment: Thanks Wietse and Roland. My data is in SQL server, I'm not sure how can I define it as na.string when importing:  `con <- dbConnect(odbc(), 
                 Driver = "SQL Server", 
                 Server = "localhost\\SQLEXPRESS", 
                 Database = "datawarehouse", 
                 Trusted_Connection = "True")`